# why 2 different ways to display the result of a class method? PHP

Tags: php

I have found that there are 2 different ways I can display the result of a class method. One by using an object operator, and the other by calling the method as a function. I want to know why and what is best.

Take the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Cats</title>
      <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
    </head>
    <body>
      <p>
        <?php
        class Cat {
            public $isAlive = true;
            public $numLegs = 4;
            public $name;
            public function __construct($name) {
                $this->name = $name;    
            }
            public function meow() {
               return "Meio meow";
            } 
        }
        $Cat1 = new Cat(CodeCat);
        echo $Cat1->meow;
        ?>
      </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I can alternatively echo the return of the method by:

```
echo meow($Cat1);
```

Whats da dealio? Whats better
Thanks for replies!
-Adrian

Comment: The difference is that `echo meow($Cat1);` does not work?

Comment: So does... `echo meow->$Cat1;`

Comment: I think you have made a mistake. meow - is not an object

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is doesn't make sense and neither examples work.

Comment: And what is `CodeCat`?

Comment: *"I can alternatively echo the return of the method by:"* (No you won't) --- If you use `echo meow($Cat1);` you will get this error `Fatal error: Call to undefined function meow()` --- What you need to do is `echo $Cat1->meow();` and not `echo meow->$Cat1;` (if anything)

Comment: Sorry I got it backwards as you say. I realized this and rushed back here to edit but you guys have already shit on it pretty hard.

Comment: I thought echo meow($Cat1) worked becouse the online lesson I was doing alowed it. Not sure why.

Comment: I don't see how this is off topic though, my question was why does it work and the answer was that it does not. Seems legit.

Comment: And, did you not try it, just as you have it now? If so, and you're going to say "yes", then I say: no/impossible. I tested your code and that's what I got out of it, my comment above. Read the answer below, it may shed a bit of light on the subject. Plus, you may want to read up a bit on this => http://us3.php.net/manual/en/classobj.examples.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok lets start by using some code that would actually run.

```
<?php
class Cat {
    public $isAlive = true;
    public $numLegs = 4;
    public $name;
    public function __construct($name) {
        $this->name = $name;    
    }
    public function meow() {
       return "Meio meow";
    } 
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Cats</title>
  <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
</head>
<body>
      <p>
<?php
    $Cat1 = new Cat('Fluffy');
    echo $Cat1->meow();
    echo $Cat1->name;
?>
      </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Now because you have defined the cats name property as public `public $name;` you are allowed to access its value in a totally unrestricted way from any code using this class with either syntax:

```
$Cat1 = new Cat('Fluffy');
echo $Cat1->name;
//or
echo $Cat1->meow();
//or even set a new value for its name after instantiating it
$Cat1->name = 'Tiddles';
```

However if you had a property that you didn't want a developer to mess with without being able to check the value first you could define this new property as private so for example 'private $owner;'

Now it is not allowed to use the syntax:

```
$Cat1->owner = 'Adrian';
```

because it is a private property, but you still want the user of your class to be able to set a value for the `owner` property, so you would create a `public method` like your `meow()` method that would set the value of this private property but only if it passed some required test like so:

```
<?php
    class Cat {
        public $isAlive = true;
        public $numLegs = 4;
        public $name;

        private $owner;

        public function __construct($name) {
            $this->name = $name;    
        }
        public function meow() {
           return "Meio meow";
        } 

        public function setOwner($var) {
            if ( $var == 'Adrian' || $var == 'Rocky' ) {
               $this->owner = $var;
            } else {
               $this->owner = 'Unknown';
               throw new Exception( 'Invalid owners name' );
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

So you have created a public method to allow access to your private property but only if it meets some specified condition.

Its basiclly a way of controlling access to the properties that require specific values

I suggest you give the documentation [a good coat of looking at](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)
as there is also a `protected` qualifier as well as public and private.

Comment: Hey thanks for the great answer. I will have to come back and read this later, but just wanted to let you know I finnaly noticed your reply.